# Is Oracle's ORA_HASH "random"?

Tags: oracle, ora-hash

Ora_hash is deterministic in that the keeping the input and seed constant will produce a definite output.

But, for any seed (including the default), will the output of an ora_hash necessarily have the property that:

"No method exists that can be used to predict what the result of an ORA_HASH will be with any level of success higher than purely random guessing?"

Comment: Your first statement is not completely correct.  At least for LOBs, it is not deterministic.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9450381/409172) for an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably not, no.  `ORA_HASH` is not designed as a particularly robust hashing algorithm-- it's certainly not something you would use as part of a cryptography library, for example, you'd use the `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH` choosing an appropriate algorithm and options.  `ORA_HASH` is designed to distribute items into buckets effectively (i.e. what happens when you hash partition a table) and to be a relatively lightweight hashing algorithm.  It is not designed to be secure from attack.

Comment: The use case I am concerned with is sampling for data analysis. Am I potentially introducing bias by selecting a random subset of data in this way?

Comment: Yes, it's a hash function designed to fill buckets approximately evenly, but it's very likely that all the items in one bucket will have some common arbitrary property--for instance, if it's a number, the numbers might all be "X modulo N = the same value", or if it's a string, items with similar-looking leading characters might bucket together.

Comment: @Jeremy - If you want a random sample, I'd use one of the `dbms_crypto.random*` methods or, if you're slightly less paranoid, `dbms_random.value`.

Comment: @Jeremy - another way to get a random sample from a table is using the `SAMPLE` keyword.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp `SAMPLE` [may not be accurate enough in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029271/409172).  It's good enough for a quick sample, and good enough for the optimizer, but probably not good enough for serious statistics work.