# hash function to generate hash value with only 5 digits in java

Tags: java, oracle, hash

I have used [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) method from `String` API and it is generating value as 99162322 for the below code:

```
String str = "hello";           
System.out.println(str.hashCode());
```

Is there any Java API which generate a hash value with only 5 digits (63346) like Oracle SQL as below?

```
select ORA_HASH('hello','99999') from dual  --63346
```

Answer (score 5):

Oracle's `ora_hash` function is designed to provide a hash code [for distributing items into buckets efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903130/is-oracles-ora-hash-random).  That makes the purpose of the function with no maximum equivalent to the purpose Java's `hashCode()` method.

It appears that in Oracle the maximum value argument just takes the modulus of the hash code by the maximum value + 1.

```
SQL> select ora_hash('hello', 49999) from dual;

ORA_HASH('HELLO',49999)
-----------------------
                  13346
```

In Java, to provide an equivalent value, you can obtain the remainder of dividing the hash code by that maximum value plus one.

```
int hash = str.hashCode() % (max + 1);  // max could be 99999
```

However, the hashing algorithms for `String` and Oracle are different, so the values will differ.

```
String s = "hello";
System.out.println(s.hashCode() % 100000);
```

Output:

```
62322
```

Also, the range of a Java hash code is that of a signed `int`, and the range of `ora_hash` is that of an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you need this, but you could MOD the result, for example...

```
String h = "blah";

int hash = h.hashCode() % 100000; // Would give numbers from 0-99999
int hash = h.hashCode() % 10000; // Would give numbers from 0-9999
```

I suppose you need it to return exactly the same number as the Oracle function thought right?

Comment: Thanks for response Bret. yes similar to Oracle, but I need Unique hash code. for ex "str1***".hashcode%10000 should not same as as "str***".hashcode%10000. with MOD i may get same results with different String right?

Comment: @SudarsanaKasireddy - in this context, there's not really any such thing as a "unique" hash code - especially if you've only got 5 digits to represent every possible string that you could ever create. As stated below, the "hashCode" in Java is basically used to organise data into a series of "buckets". The "equals" method can be used to tell if two instances with the same hash code are the same "thing" or not. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Tks Bret...I will try different way to generate unique values with 5 digits

Comment: @SudarsanaKasireddy Unless your strings are less than 6 digits long and contain only numbers, this will be impossible

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do this would simply be to use modulus, i.e.:

```
int hash = str.hashCode() % 100000; // results 0-99999
```

However, whenever you create a hash function, you need to be aware of a high possibility of collisions, which can affect performance.

Do you need your hash function to output exactly the same hash for a string as the Oracle Hash? [Note that `ORA_HASH` can return any max, by specifying the `max_bucket` argument. See linked documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions112.htm#SQLRF06313)

Further reading: [What is a good Hash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function)